# Angular: bootstrap backdrop is displayed when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm doing error handling on my app and I want to pop up a bootstrap modal whenever I have an error.

At first I want my backdrop and error modal to have display 'none'. When there is an error I would like the backdrop + error modal to pop-up. I am able to hide the modal when I load the webpage, but unfortunately the backdrop isn't hidden (there is a dark grey background and I can't even click it to make it disappear. Can someone see why? Modal and backdrop elements both have the same '[ngStyle]="{'display': display}"' that is linked to the error component property.

**error.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {ErrorService} from "./error.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-error',
    templateUrl: './error.component.html',
    styles: [`
        .backdrop {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    `]
})

export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {
    error: Error;
    displayed = 'none'

    constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) {

    }

    onErrorHandled() {
        this.display = 'none'
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.errorService.errorOccurred.subscribe(
            (error: Error) => {
                this.error = error;
                this.display = 'block';
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**error.component.html**

```
<div class="backdrop" [ngStyle]="{'display': display}"></div>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" [ngStyle]="{'display': display}">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="onErrorHandled()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{ error?.title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>{{ error?.message }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="onErrorHandled()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: try adding the backdrop class to your backdrop div dynamically as well with ngClass and see if that helps

Comment: That's also an option indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe is because you have 2 variables "displayed" and "display"

Answer (score 1):

Use the native Bootstrap 4 class `d-none` for hiding things. IF you are using Bootstrap 4 that is.

No need for custom css.